# Install oracle imp / exp in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, oracle, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, oracleclient

I have this Ubuntu version:

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

I just download `oracle-instantclient12.2-basiclite-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm` and install the tools using

```
alien -i oracle-instantclient12.2-basiclite-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

But I can't find the `exp` anywhere, just these 2 files

```
root@localhost:/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/bin# ls -la
total 108
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Nov  8 14:47 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Nov  8 14:47 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43797 Mar 16  2017 adrci
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 56984 Mar 16  2017 genezi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The utilities are not part of the basic (or basiclite) package. The [instant client download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html) lists the packages and what they contain. You need to get the tools package, `oracle-instantclient12.2-tools-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm`, in addition to the basic package, to be able to use `exp` and `imp` (and their datapump equivalents; and SQL*Loader).

You may find the SQL*Plus package useful as well.